# Get Transcrypt to output readable files

Tags: javascript, python, transcrypt

I'm trying to translate the following test code with Transcrypt:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 5
```

The output is a 2447 line file:

```
$ transcrypt test.py -fb -e 6
$ wc -l __javascript__/test.js
2447 __javascript__/test.js
```

How can I get Transcrypt to generate sane output for this input?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File `test.js` has got the whole runtime lib in it.
Look at the module file instead, it's called `test.mod.js` and has only code for this one module. You can reduce its size further by using the `-xc` compiler switch.

If you e.g. take a look at:

http://www.transcrypt.org/live/turtle_site/turtle_site.html

and change the program, e.g. change `'red'` to `'pink'`, and then press `[Compile and run]`, then the module file is the only thing that's reloaded.
That's why the response is fast.

Comment: Thanks!
Looks like Transcrypt doesn't do what I want. I just want to translate a Python class into the most idiomatic JS equivalent. JavaScripthon seems to do this pretty well.

Comment: For Transcrypt a high priority was supporting multiple inheritance and assignment of bound methods, like `aFunction = anObject.aMethod`. This leads to methods being properties rather than plain functions. Other tools strike a different balance. Another good tool that generates short, readable JS code resembling the Python original is RapydScript.